# how to fix java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class in appium with jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, appium, appium-android

I am running my test using Appium Java with integration in jenkins, and I use Jenkins `build now` to debug my test run (since I need to simulate test in CI/CD process and make sure that it will run in jenkins).

note: I already set some of env variable in jenkins

here is my structure(page object model) :

`Baseclass.java`

```
public class BaseClass {
    public AndroidDriver driver;
    public PageObject pageObject;
    
    
    public static String userName = System.getenv("USERNAME"); // JimWOrm_AkxAuc
    public static String accessKey = System.getenv("ACCESSKEY");  // PfrH3CPzJttGb8F6cxgl
    
    public static String buildName = System.getenv("BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME"); 
    public static String app = System.getenv("APP_ID"); bs://ffdf74d0b5ccf9f84ee79735f505fadf12288514

    public static String url = "http://"+userName+":"+accessKey+"@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";
        
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        MutableCapabilities capabilities = new UiAutomator2Options();
        
        HashMap<String, Object> browserstackOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        browserstackOptions.put("appiumVersion", "1.18.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("bstack:options", browserstackOptions);
        
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy S21");
        capabilities.setCapability("os_Version", "12.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("Project","Sample project Jenkins Integration"); 
        capabilities.setCapability("build", buildName); 

        capabilities.setCapability("app", app); 

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(url), capabilities);
        
        pageObject = new PageObject(driver);
        
    }

   
   
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

`Login.java`

```
package com.browserstack;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login extends BaseClass {
    
    @Test
    public void login () throws InterruptedException {
        //app loading
        pageObject.appLoading(); 
        
        //click and send in namefield
        pageObject.clickOnElement(pageObject.nameField);
        pageObject.enterUsersname(pageObject.nameField);
        
        //hide keyboard
        pageObject.hideKeyboard();
        
        //submit
        pageObject.clickOnElement(pageObject.loginbtn);
        
        System.out.print("Test Login : Complete");
        
    }
}
```

`PageObject.java`

```
package pages;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import Utility.utils;

public class PageObject extends Utils {
    AndroidDriver driver;

    public PageObject(AndroidDriver driver) {

        super(driver);
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
        
    }

    // page object
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.androidsample.sampleapp:id/nameField")
    public WebElement nameField;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.androidsample.sampleapp:id/btnLetsShop")
    public WebElement loginbtn;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/country")
    public WebElement countrybtn;
    
    //methods
    public void appLoading() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void navigateBack() {
        driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
```

`Utils.java`

```
package utility;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class Utils {
    static AndroidDriver driver;
    
    public Utils(AndroidDriver driver) {
        Utils.driver=driver;
    }
    
    
    public static void scrollDown() throws InterruptedException {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: scrollGesture", ImmutableMap.of(
                "left", 100, "top", 450, "width", 200, "height", 950,
                "direction", "DOWN",
                "percent", 10
            ));
    }
```

`xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="First">
    <test name="FirstTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.browserstack.Login"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

after `build now` run in jenkins here is the result:
`console output in jenkins run`

```
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 30.001 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] setUp(com.browserstack.Login)  Time elapsed: 29.903 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @b62d79
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @b62d79
```

`browserstack issue result`

```
STOP SESSION
[BROWSERSTACK_IDLE_TIMEOUT] Session timed out due to inactivity for configured time interval (default: 90 secs)
```

how to fix this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class
```

Am I missing something? or should I tweak/change my structure of page object model?

Comment: Please raise a ticket with Browserstack at support@browserstack.com